# how verify the OneToMany relationship between two entities

Tags: hibernate, entity, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have two entites Parent and Child with OneToMany relationship in Hibernate, Parent has many Childs, I want to check if the Parent has Childs or not

I used these conditions and they not working

```
if (parent.getChilds().size() == 0)
```

and

```
if (parent.getChilds.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are equivalent. If you look at source of, for example, `ArrayList#isEmpty()` you'll find

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
```